# Ajax array list passing

Tags: arrays, ajax, vb.net

Im trying to pass multiple array list in one ajax call. Can someone please help me?

Array

```
var arraylist = [{name: name1, age: age1}, {name: name2, age: age2}, ...]
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
        url: "api/postProductLink",
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: "POST",
        data: { Info: arraylist},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {

        }
    });
```

backend vb.net

```
<HttpPost>
<POST("api/postProductLink")> _
Public Function postProductLink(data As ProductMerchandiseModel) As ResponseCallBack
    'code here
End Function
```

model

```
Public Class ProductMerchandiseModel
Public name As String
Public age As Integer End Class
```

I want to individually pull each name and age.

Thanks!

Comment: Show the model which you are expecting at back-end. Show some back-end code. What is your back-end? Probably, ASP.NET WebAPI, right?

Comment: since you are passing the JSON data to server..you need to `stringify` your data.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX call should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "api/postProductLink",
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify(arrayList),// Since your contentType is JSON.
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {

    }
});
```